# Printing unicodes in Python

Tags: python, unicode

In python, how can I iterate through a text file and count the occurences of unicodes? As i am very new to python.

```
with open ('bengali.txt') as infile:
  for infile in range(0x0985,0x0989):
    print unichr(infile)
```

Is this Correct Code??

Comment: Where is the counting part? And you are a beginner and [use Python 2](https://pythonclock.org/)? I suggest, you start using Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to check `range(0x0985,0x0989)`, you can do:

```
count = 0
with open('bengali.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
  for line in infile:
      for char in line:
          if ord(char) in range(0x0985,0x0989):
              count += 1
```

Edit: Print characters:

```
for x in range(0x0985,0x0989):
    print(chr(x))
```

Edit 2: Count characters:

```
counter = {}
for x in range(0x0985,0x0989):
    counter[x] = 0

with open('bengali.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
  for line in infile:
      for char in line:
          n = ord(char)
          if n in range(0x0985,0x0989):
              counter[n] += 1

for key, value in counter.items():
    print(chr(key), value)
```

Comment: How do print Individual Unicode in that range? Count is working fine

Comment: I added the code, don't forget to mark as solved. :)

Comment: অ-1
আ-1
ই-2
ঈ-4   I want to print like this for example.... Those characters are occurring those many times in that text file...

Comment: I added the counter.

Comment: my_unicode=(0x0985,0x0986,0x0987,0x0988,0x0989,0x098A,0x098B,0x098F) I want print these unicodes.For this range will not work. Whats the alternative??

Comment: Then use `my_unicode` instead of `range(0x0985,0x0989)`. And mark the answer as solved.